# Before/After properties without change are not equal in firestore-triggered Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a firestore collection called `events` that contains documents with the fields `begin`, `end` and `title`.
The function is triggered if a document was changed.

`begin` and `end` are of type `timestamp`.
I want my function to `return false` if `begin` or `end` was changed.

In my cloud function, I check if the respective before and after data is equal, however `true` is returned, even though only the field `title` was changed.

```
const before = change.before.data()
const after = change.after.data()

//begin and end weren't changed. Still, true is returned
if (before?.begin == after?.begin && before?.end == after?.end) {
    return false
}
return true
```

When comparing the milliseconds, it works:

```
const before = change.before.data()
const after = change.after.data()

//begin and end weren't changed. false is returned    
if (before?.begin.toMillis() == after?.begin.toMillis() && before?.end.toMillis() == after?.end.toMillis()) {
    return false
}
```

What causes this? Shouldn't I be able to compare the `Timestamp` objects itself instead of comparing it using a member function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shouldn't I be able to compare the Timestamp objects itself instead of comparing it using a member function?

No, the `==` operator in JavaScript, when applied to objects, only compares the references to the two objects.  It does not compare them deeply.  So, it will only yield true if the two objects are the exact same object.

If you want to compare two [Timestamp](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Timestamp.html) objects, you will need to compare them deeply.  As you can see from the linked API documentation, there is a [isEqual](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Timestamp.html#isEqual) method provided on Timestamp that will do that for you.

```
before?.begin.isEqual(after?.begin)
```

When you used `toMillis`, what you were doing was comparing two JavaScript number objects, which are compared by their actual values more intuitively.  It is also not an exact comparison in this case, since Timestamp can represent nanosecond precision times.  Conversion to milliseconds loses data.

Comment: I didn't know that the `==` operator compares references of objects. This makes a lot of sense.
In my case the `toMillies()` method was sufficient as I am only storing minute precise values as timestamps. Still, `isEqual` seems like the perfect solution. Thank you.